# Equivalence of Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-riemann-equations

You have the CR equations in polar and cartesian coördinates that are equivalent if f(z) is complex differentiable because you can use the chain rule on u and v but if f isn't differentiable you can find an easy example where only the x-y CR hold but the polar partials don't even exist. My question now is is there a less strict requirement (than complex differentiable) under which the CR are equivalent?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150056/discussion-on-question-by-lowie-equivalence-of-cauchy-riemann-equations); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.